# Disabling OSB JMS Proxies

Tags: jms, weblogic12c, osb

Does OSB Proxy service gets auto enabled after server restart ? I have a JMS proxy service which subscribes to a JMS queue  but my target is down so I have disabled the state field from Operational tab for that particular proxy. Is it possible if the if the server is restarted the proxy service is auto enabled ? I am using Weblogic 12C .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy services wont be enabled even after server restart